# Issue with CSS Borders and Overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, border

I'm having an issue with overflow and displaying a border.

I have content in an unordered list which I have set to `overflow: scroll;`
Problem is, when I set a border to the unordered list, the border does not extend to the elements which overflow.

I would like the border for `#times` and `#channel-rows ul`, to extend and cover the elements that are outside the border. K L M N O P are not in the border. Content in Row B is not covered by the border too. How do I get these elements into the same border as the elements before it?

Can someone provide an example on how to make the border extend into the overflow area?

Please see JSFiddle.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H25mR/).

Comment: can you post some HTML, CSS, a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: has your ulcontainer the overflow set too?

Comment: I am guessing, does this solve your issue? http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/LzHWM/

Comment: Please see the JSFiddle in original post @SW4

Comment: @faby please see the example. I need multiple unordered lists to scroll together. - thanks

Comment: @Glitchezz wich is the border that make the code not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Add a wrapper to the scrollable content with `display:table`

2) Set width:100% on the children `#times` and `#channel-rows`

Enjoy!

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/H25mR/1/)**

Comment: This is rather clever, tables must be painted differently than block level elements.

Comment: **NOTE** does not work IE 11 or may have undesired effect if using. I switched to `display:inline-block;` and it worked as I wanted as well but this got me started.

Answer (score 0):

remove fixed width from #times and #channel-rows  and it solve your problem. If you want I update your fiddle.

```
#times {
    float:right;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 738px /*<-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM*/;
    border: 2px solid grey;
}

#channel-rows {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00FFFB;
    float:right;
    height: auto;
    width: 738px/*<-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM*/;;
}
```

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't work. The border still doesn't extend into the scroll area.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand wich is the wrong border. If you tell me which is I'll remove it to show how should be.

Comment: there is no 'wrong border'. I would like the border for #times and #channel-rows ul, to extend and cover the elements that are outside the border. K L M N O P are not in the border. Neither is all the content in Row B. How do I get these into the same border as the elements before it?

Comment: the problem is #channel-rows and #times  width  fixed.  Give them higher width